# Accessing the paging data from a native script in ElasticSearch

Tags: scripting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am currently using a native script written in Java to filter the search results based on various forms of access control. The problem is that the access control verification takes a ridiculous amount of time per-record. There are some ways we can improve somewhat, but we came up with a work-around that will improve it drastically. The only problem is that I'm not sure if I can do it the way I want.

The solution: I need to stop assessing the access controls after the relevant number of results have been found.

The problem: I can't figure out how to access the offset and page size from within the script (implementing AbstractSearchScript at the moment) in order to decide when I've reached my minimum results. Does anyone have any idea how to get this data "properly" without making it a separate parameter of the script?

The bonus: I need to return a number of hits that is close to or larger than the actual number of hits. Since elasticsearch doesn't cache the results of the query, I can work around the problem by simply returning true for every result past the relevant ones. But I'd like to work a solution closer to Google's where I return a number of remaining results based on what percentage of the data was a hit so far. However, to do this (and to avoid potential complications) I'd like to just modifying the hits data directly. Is there any way to do this from a script?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the "terminate_after" parameter introduced in ES 1.4, rather than trying to implement this yourself.

For your "bonus," I would just run the query a second time without the ACLs.

Comment: I assume you're referring to this? http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html What's the practical difference between "size" and "terminate_after"? (Sorry, the documentation's not great.)

Comment: "terminate_after" is per-shard, and "size" is on the collecting server.  If you have 4 shards, and you set size=100, each shard will deliver 100 results to the collector, which will sort them and discard the unneeded 300.  If you have reason to believe that all shards have results of equal quality, you could size=100&terminate_after=25, and each shard will do roughly 25% of the work.